How to compute equilibrium of a discrete time system?

I know that a continuous time system $\dot{x}= f(x) $ has an equilibrium at $x_0$ s.t $f(x_0)=0.$
But I cannot translate the same idea in discrete-time systems since there we are given the system as a difference equation.
What is the analog of demanding the derivative to be zero ?.
My book skips the discrete time systems as an exercise for the reader: $x_{k+1}=Ax_k$.
So imagine a simple system like:
$$
x_{k+1}=2x_k(1-x_k)
$$
I was thinking that the analog of the zero derivative is requiring $x_{k+1}-x_k=0$

Edit: It was pointed out to me that it's better to call it "a fixed point"

This is correct, and is more commonly known as a fixed point of the system. (For the analog of periodic functions, one has $x_{k+n}=x_k$ as an $n$-periodic point.)

What is "equilibrium" ? It indicates that when some "operation" or some "event" occurs , the System will remain unchanged. Thus Continuous Case $x=f(x)$, Like-wise Discrete Case : with $x_{n+1}=f(x_{n})$ , we want $x_{n}=f(x_{n})$ , hence $x_{n+1}=x_{n}$.

so here $2x_k(1-x_k) = x_k $?

Equilibrium of discrete time system is $x^s = f(x^s, u^s)$
